# Can we detect request type (from html or user client) by node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a file path and I want different action due to different client, here is what I planned

```
if (userclient) {
  res.send(<a>View it here</a> <a>download it here</a>);
} else {
  res.send(data);
  //       ^^^^ data is a variable of the file that we're serving
}
```

So I want my code above can serve an HTML that let user select to download or view it but serve file for bot/API/HTML linking (`<link src="/path/to/style.css">`), but how can I detect it's a user client, not an HTML file requesting stylesheet or other??

Comment: FYI, it's generally bad form to serve entirely different content to different clients for the same URL request. I'd suggest you either use different URLs for different content or use a query parameter to differentiate.  Also Google can penalize you in search results if you serve its bots different content than you serve a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no perfect solution, but you could use the [User agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) to detect what type of client it is.

For example, your typical browser's user agent will look something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36` (This is my current User Agent on Chrome)

Google's bot's agent is `Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)`, and the user agent for requests sent from a PHP server is blank (by default). You could treat all requests as bots except for ones that contain the words "Chrome", "Mozilla", "AppleWebKit", "Safari", etc. in them.

Although, you probably *should* just have two separate pages, one for your API and one for the user. This will prevent any complications and confusion. Keep in mind it is also possible to change your user agent, so a bot could have a user agent that looks like a user and a user could have a user agent that looks like a bot.

Comment: How about what's the agent value if it's linked by a html page (`<link src="http://domain/path/to/style.css">`)